# Slide on Bootstrap 3 Carousel error

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

I'm working with a Bootstrap 3 carousel. Here is what I have done far, I want it to look similar to this.

[image]

Why does the slide preview from column 2 anytime I click the arrows? Is there a way to hide the preview from showing up when clicking next/previous

[image]

Anytime I click past two slides, it errors out and doesn't go back to the first slide.

[image]

```css
<style type="text/css">
 /* #information, #video {
     width: 50%;               //CSS styling for table tags.
 } */
 .linebreak { 
        display: none;
    }
    .image {
   float: left!important;
 }
 .carousel slide {
  width: 400px;
 }
 .text {
  width: 45%!important;
  float: right!important;
  right: 14px!important;
  /* top: 10px!important; */
  margin-right: 35px!important;
  /* margin-top: 20px!important; */
 }
 .carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
    }
    .carousel img {
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
 }
    .carousel-control active {
  position: fixed;
 }
 .carousel {
  margin-top: 40px;
 }
 .firstcolumn {
  width: 1000px;
}
 /*.video-container {
 /*position:relative;
 padding-bottom:315px;
 padding-top:10px; /* width: 100% ;* max-width: 500px; padding-right:0px;
 /*max-height:530px; overflow: auto;
 border: none;
 }
    .video-container img {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 max-width: 500px;
 max-height:530px;
 height:100%;
 margin: 0px;*/
 /*}*/
 </style>
```

```html
<div class="firstcolumn">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> <!-- DIV 1 BEGIN -->
         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.evantage-technology.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/product_office365.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    <div class="text">Office 365 is the brand name Microsoft uses for a group of subscriptions that provide productivity software and related services.</div>
  </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="image" src="http://office365.ecolearning.eu/img/office_icos/delve-logo.png" alt="Chicago">
      <div class="text">Microsoft Office Delve is a data visualization and discovery tool that incorporates elements of social networking and machine learning with the search capability of the Microsoft Office 365 suite.</div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div> -->

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="margin-top: 50px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="margin-top: 50px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- DIV 1 END -->
 <div class="secondcolumn">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <center><h3>WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO?</h3></center>
          <br/>
        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">.col-sm-3</div>
     <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">.col-sm-6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">.col-sm-3</div>
     <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">.col-sm-6</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This question appears to have been completely rewritten after an answer came in. Please do not do that! It has the effect of invalidating the work received in the helpful answer(s) you received, and makes their answer nonsensical in the context of the new question. If you accept/tick an answer below, and have a related or follow-up question, then either ask it in the comments (if it is really trivial) or post a fresh question. You can link to a prior question if you feel it would help with context.

Comment: (Where a question would benefit from an update to the text, you can sometimes get away with adjusting the question if you have not received any answers, but otherwise it is good to put it at the end, so it is in the correct chronological order. It makes little sense to new readers to put it at the start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make use of the Bootstrap Grid inside your `Carousel` component you can avoid using *any* customized CSS.  You just need to structure your HTML accordingly:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.evantage-technology.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/product_office365.jpg" alt="Los Angeles"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-8">Office 365 is the brand name Microsoft uses for a group of subscriptions that provide productivity software and related services.</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-2"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://office365.ecolearning.eu/img/office_icos/delve-logo.png" alt="Chicago"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-10">Microsoft Office Delve is a data visualization and discovery tool that incorporates elements of social networking and machine learning with the search capability of the Microsoft Office 365 suite.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <h3 class="text-center">WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO?</h3>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">A</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">B</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">C</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">D</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may need to expand the snippet to view its responsive nature.  I would also point out that you were using elements like `<center>` which were depreciated, or attributes like `align="center"` on your `<div>` elements.  You should use CSS for this sort of positioning, which with respect to Bootstrap would involve applying the `text-center` class to the element whose contents you wish to be centered.

Comment: Thanks for the input Robert! That fixed the carousel issue with the right arrow not working properly. How do I make the text fit inside the margins? here is my error.

Comment: The problem is your custom CSS; it's overriding default behavior of several Bootstrap components (like Grid) and causing alignment issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Robert, I have upvoted and chosen this as the preferred answer.